# How to clone a triple booted HDD?

Tags: multi-boot, clone

I have a triple-booted 120GB HDD (Lubuntu 14.04,OSX 10.5,WinXP) in my Macbook and will soon upgrade it to a 128GB SSD. Now how should I go about doing this the easiest way? I don't really want to meddle around reinstalling and reconfiguring all OSes again, so is there a way I can just repartition the disk through a live CD and somehow copy the data over there? I read CloneZilla could be used, but are there things I should keep in mind while doing so?

When mounted through Sata to USB converter, the HDD looks like this:

```
Device    Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System  
/dev/sdc1               1      409639      204819+  ee  GPT  
/dev/sdc2          409640    52576295    26083328   af  HFS / HFS+  
/dev/sdc3        52838440   173361767    60261664   83  Linux  
/dev/sdc4   *   173623912   226053007    26214548    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Comment: A full disk copy (not the OS, not the file systems, but the whole disk) should do the trick. And there are plenty of posts in [su] explaining that though I am not sure how many are relevant to OSX.

Comment: @Hennes okay thanks. Thats okay, ironically the only OS out of those three I cant run smoothly anymore is OSX anyway... Although that might change after the disk upgrade